# Web Api add a location to a user

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I want to add a location to a  user (My userDto has a list of location he wants to visit)

```
[HttpPut]
         [Route("{id:guid}/location/")]
        public IHttpActionResult AddLocationToUser(Guid idUser , LocationDto location)
        {
            _userLogic.AddLocationToUser(idUser, location);
            return Ok();
        }
```

it's ok to make a Put ? (because I have a function who just add a location to a list in user and then I want to update ) but how my route should look like ???

It's ok [Route("{id:guid}/location/")] ??

I pass the userId from session , but It's ok to send the whole location in PUT??

Comment: I assume you'll be calling it from an AJAX call, right? Does the location have an ID? You could pass a json like {guid: "GUID_GOES_HERE", locationId: "LOCATION_ID"}, and on your AddLocationToUser, you'd pass the location ID, not the DTO

Comment: Personally, I'd route like: 'api/api_project/Users/GUID/AddLocation/LocationID

Comment: Please reffer to http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-routing-conventions, for api routing conventions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is adding/creating a record, you want to use **HttpPost**. For LocationDto, you want to use **[FromBody]**.

For example,

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("{id:guid}/location")]
public IHttpActionResult AddLocationToUser(Guid id, [FromBody] LocationDto location)
{
   _userLogic.AddLocationToUser(id, location);
   return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I second @Win's suggestion of using HttpPost. If you are using Web Api 2, then the following is another alternative.

**Controller:**

```
public class LocationController : ApiController
{
    UserLogic _userLogic;
    public LocationController()
    {
        _userLogic = new UserLogic();
    }
    public void PostLocationToUser(LocationViewModel locationViewModel)
    {
        _userLogic.AddLocationToUser(locationViewModel.UserId, locationViewModel.Location);
    }
}
```

**View Model:**

```
public class LocationViewModel
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    public string Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

**JSON:**

```
var input = {
    UserId: "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111",
    Location: {
        Latitude: "anotherLatitude",
        Longitude: "anotherLongitude"
    }
};
```

I used the default Web Api routing, the url is "/api/Location", and the PostLocationToUser returns a status code of 204 (no content).